# psutil module is not installing

Tags: pip, python-module, psutil

I am trying to install `psutil` Python module using pip but it gives me error.

I have update python from 3.9 to 3.10 then this error is coming. I also uninstalled 3.9
version but this error continues

ERROR IS :

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install psutil
Collecting psutil
  Using cached psutil-5.8.0.tar.gz (470 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for psutil, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: psutil
    Running setup.py install for psutil ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Offensive Tech\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f3q85m4u\\psutil_e7ab251360d04370903c55726eaf62e4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Offensive Tech\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f3q85m4u\\psutil_e7ab251360d04370903c55726eaf62e4\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v2wyl0ki\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\psutil'
         cwd: C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f3q85m4u\psutil_e7ab251360d04370903c55726eaf62e4\
    Complete output (38 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psaix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psbsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_pslinux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psosx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psposix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_pssunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_pswindows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\runner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_aix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_bsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_contracts.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_linux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_memleaks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_misc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_osx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_process.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_sunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_system.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_testutils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_unicode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_windows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    running build_ext
    building 'psutil._psutil_windows' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Offensive Tech\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f3q85m4u\\psutil_e7ab251360d04370903c55726eaf62e4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Offensive Tech\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f3q85m4u\\psutil_e7ab251360d04370903c55726eaf62e4\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v2wyl0ki\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Offensive Tech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\psutil' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Anyone tell Me the Solution for This Error . I want to install To this module.

Comment: The error is telling you what to do - `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

Answer (score 0):

First install [this](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe) 
then download the psutil from this [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#psutil)
and then install it using

```
pip install python_package.whl
```

if it didn't work run this before installing the module

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

fist istall this:

```
pip install pipwin
```

next use the pipwin to istall your module:

```
pipwin install (package name)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).